# Where does the member variable inside a class allocated?

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class Sample
{
   string strName;
};
```

If i create an object for the Sample using `Sample *obj = new Sample()` where does the string `strName` created? is it in stack or in heap?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't define "stack" and "heap", so theoretically it's up to compiler, as long as lifetime semantics is preserved. Moreover, `std::string` may keep its actual data wherever it wants to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowhere, because `Sample obj = new Sample()` won't compile.

If you mean `Sample* obj = new Sample()`, then it's in dynamic storage (heap).

When you call `delete obj`, the string will be deleted automatically, even if it's on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

The whole og `obj` is on "the heap", and so is its data member. However, you do not have to worry about managing the memory assigned to the data members. Deleting `obj` will take care of the string too.

Answer (score 1):

Structs, arrays, pointers and the basic numeric types will be created with the class wherever the class is allocated.

Strings are more complex. They are a sort of a container. The members of string that define the container will be stored on class' memory block as a member inside your sample class. The String's text will probably be allocated somewhere else on the heap (depends on the string class implementation).

Now, if you do `Sample* blah = new Sample();` then operator new will allocate memory in the heap (the pointer will be on the stack, or on the heap if it's originally a member of a class on the heap).
If you just use it as a variable, it will be stored on the stack: `Sample blah;`

Comment: *Now, if you do Sample* blah = new Sample(); then operator new will allocate memory in the heap (the pointer will be on the stack).* Not if the pointer is a member of a class created on the heap itself! **Heapception**

Comment: right. added that.  hard to think about every example when trying to be thorough :)

Answer (score 1):

`strName` will be placed where your `Sample` object is placed. However, class `string` may under the hood address whatever storage it likes, whether is uses normal variables (then again they are placed where the `string` is placed, pointers to something, memory maps, are all the time just queries an XML interface from the other side of the earth.

However, `string` has to somehow store the addresses, so e.g. its pointers or references or urls or whatever addressing scheme is used, are placed where the `string` is placed.

---

*Related Rule of thumb*: Pointers are in itself values (which is why the are hard to handle correctly in object copying situations).