# Are the members of a heap allocated class automatically allocated in the heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, allocation

Let's say I have:

```
class A{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And I allocate an A instance like:

```
A *a = new A();
```

Does a.x and a.y are also allocated in the heap, since they are 'dependent' of a heap allocated object?

Thank you.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343015/where-does-the-member-variable-inside-a-class-allocated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class members and explicit stack/heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836591/class-members-and-explicit-stack-heap-allocation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to understand that C++ uses "copy semantic". This means that variables and structure fields do not contain references to values, but the values themselves.

When you declare

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    double yarr[20];
};
```

each `A` you will create will contain an integer and an array of 20 doubles... for example its size in bytes will be `sizeof(int)+20*sizeof(double)` and possibly more for alignment reasons.

When you allocate an object `A` on the heap all those bytes will be in the heap, when you create an instace of `A` on the stack then all of those bytes will be on the stack.

Of course a structure can contain also a **pointer** to something else, and in this case the pointed memory may be somewhere else... for example:

```
struct B
{
   int x;
   double *yarr;
};
```

In this case the structure `B` contains an integer and a **pointer** to an array of doubles and the size in memory for `B` is `sizeof(int)+sizeof(double *)` and possibly a little more.
When you allocate an instance of `B` the constructor will decide where the memory pointed by `yarr` is going to be allocated from.

The standard class `std::vector` for example is quite small (normally just three pointers), and keeps all the elements on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

You will get one allocation on the heap that contains `x` and `y`. `A` is just a nice way to refer to that object.

I wish I could easily draw on Stack Overflow, but you can think of it something like this (very small) heap example:

```
        +-------------------------------+
        |            Heap               | 
        +-------------------------------+
        | Other memory here ...         | 
        +-------+-----------------------+
A *a -> | x | y | Other memory here ... |
        +-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: I meant A *a = new A(). Sorry.