# Keeping map/vector as data member

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Let's say I have class A which has a map data member.
I allocated object a (of class A) on the heap.
Where the map memory is stored? On the stack?
I'm asking since the map memory can be changed and the memory couldn't be allocated when I allocated space for the object of A class

Thanks

Comment: The contents of the map are valid as long as the object encapsulating it is valid. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826722/c-are-the-members-of-a-heap-allocated-class-automatically-allocated-in-the-hea)

Comment: A map manages its own memory (on the free store). But the object itself resides inside the A that was allocated.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Not necessarily on the free store.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, using the default allocator?

Comment: @StoryTeller: With the default allocator yeah more or less. I don't know whether even that's guaranteed tbh, but I'd guess it is.